# Что такое GCHandle ?

Tags: c#

Для чего это нужно?

Что реализует    **GCHandle.Alloc()**    ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Читаем [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/a95009h1.aspx):

> Выделяет дескриптор Normal для указанного объекта.
>
> Дескрипторы Normal являются непрозрачными, иначе говоря, адрес фиксированного объекта, используемый дескриптором, недоступен.